# POST data not saving to Mongo with Mongoose/Express

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

Can't work out why this isn't saving to Mongo Atlas - am I missing something obvious?

Model (the only thing required is the string which I'll get from a text area):

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const SnippetSchema = new Schema(
  {
    snippetContent: {type: String, required: true},
  }, {
  collection: 'snippets'
  });

const Snippet = mongoose.model("Snippet", SnippetSchema)

module.exports = Snippet;
```

Router (directs the post request to my controller at snippet_post :

```
router.post('/', producer_controller.snippet_post)
```

Controller (trying to get the body of the post request, then set that value to be the 'snippetContent' string required by my model, then save it) :

```
snippet_post = async (req, res, next) => {

    var postContent = req.body;
    console.log(postContent);
    var snippet = new snippetModel({
        'snippetContent': postContent,
    });

    try {
              await snippet.save();
              res.send(postContent);
            } catch (err) {
              res.status(500).send(err)
            }
    };
```

Pug form it should be sending the snippet data from :

```
block producer_content 
    h1 Snippet builder
    form(method='POST' action='/')
        textarea#snippet(name='snippet')

        button(type='submit') Test POST
```

Error says '`snippetContent`' (from my model) is required... but I'm sure I'm setting that to be the body of the form that is POSTed to my controller?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking at similar problem (seems there are a lot from other q's on SO!)

Because I'm using separate router files (i.e. specifying `app.use('/user', userRouter); in app.js`)
) I needed to add

```
router.use(express.json());
router.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

to my `routes` file/s.

i.e. like this...

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const producer_controller = require('../controllers/{$name_of your_controller');

//add these 2 lines to make sure the parsing functionality is passed on to access body
router.use(express.json());
router.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

//then your routes go here
router.get('/', {$your_route.1});

router.post('/', {$your_route.2)

module.exports = router;
```